# Couldnt convert to number when expanding a table power query

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a very annoying problem when i try to merge two tables on power query excel. I use one column to match records from both tables and when i try to expand the second table it pops up the following message:

DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number.
Λεπτομέρειες:
ECS

I have no idea how to fix this. The columns that are matched have text, not value. There are no errors when i import data. Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Delete the step `#"Changed Type"` in both queries
2. Make sure that the two merged columns have the same type (`text ABC`, in your case)

When you create a query from a table, Power Query try to guess (based on the first 200 lines) the [type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-change-data-types-power-query-b8618bb6-dec6-4fe6-8974-5f799856f218) of each column. Now, the value `"Λεπτομέρειες: ECS"` is probably included in a different column (than the two merged) that has `Number 123` as a type. It's kind of a mixed column (due to the source of data itself or to a delimiter issue).

Comment: Thanks! There was indeed an error in the formatting of a column. Much appreciated